# Data Manipulation of json encoded string

Tags: javascript, json, data-manipulation

I have the following JSON encoded string that I would like to manipulate using javascript such that the x and y axis values are combined into a two dimensional array names values.

```
[
  {
    "key": "0",
    "xaxis": "1492041600000",
    "yaxis": "512"
  },
  {
    "key": "0",
    "xaxis": "1492045200000",
    "yaxis": "985"
  },
  {
    "key": "1",
    "xaxis": "1492048800000",
    "yaxis": "685"
  },
  {
    "key": "1",
    "xaxis": "1492052400000",
    "yaxis": "935"
  }
]
```

I needs to render as:

```
[
  {
    "key": "0",
    "values": [
      [1492041600000, 512],
      [1492045200000, 985]
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "1",
    "values": [
      [1492048800000, 685],
      [1492052400000, 935]
    ]
  }
]
```

Can someone please show me how to perform this data manipulation?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Using `map-reduce`, you should be able to get the behavior you want.

```js
const results = [{"key":"0","xaxis":"1492041600000","yaxis":"512"},{"key":"0","xaxis":"1492045200000","yaxis":"985"},{"key":"1","xaxis":"1492048800000","yaxis":"685"},{"key":"1","xaxis":"1492052400000","yaxis":"935"}]


const reducedResults = results.reduce((acc, result) => {
  if(acc[result.key]) {
    acc[result.key].values.push([result.xaxis, result.yaxis]);
  } else {
    acc[result.key] = { key: result.key, values: [[result.xaxis, result.yaxis]] }
  }
  
  return acc;
}, {});

const newResults = Object.values(reducedResults);

console.log(newResults);
```